# How to copy a large stream to another without OutOfMemoryException in C#

Tags: c#, stream, out-of-memory, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm working on synchronizing two systems using their apis. How can i copy a massive response stream (of `HttpWebResponse`) to a request stream (of `HttpWebRequest`) without having `OutOfMemoryException` in `C#`.

CopyTo is throwing out of memory exception and I can't use byte arrays as well because they allocate contiguous memory blocks...

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, full traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  Also, a [mcve] showing code that reproduces the problem would help.

Comment: Possibly [ASP.NET Core Disable Response Buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60607912) or [Non buffered output in ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72076958) are relevant.

Comment: Take a look at the second example in the accepted answer, which allocates a small buffer, reads into it repeatedly, and writes it to the destination stream in a loop.