# live-preview-root messing up my html and css grid

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, css-grid

I have a web app that I am using CSS grid on and have never come across this before.
I have a live-preview-root div in my html and it is ruining my layout.

This is the inspect screenshot:

[image: Inspect]

This is the screenshot of what is happening to my app:

[image: Result]

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what could be happening here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

The `live-preview-root` element is being added by Visual Studio Browser Link, which is used for the "Browser Link" or "Hot Reload" feature ([Even if you have "Browser Link" disabled, it will be added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLUMk.png))

In [this forum post in Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/browser-link-cannot-be-disabled/1582653) and [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952420/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-asp-net-core-net-6-vs-2022), it looks like the "Browser Link" element and code is injected if you have "Browser Link" or "Hot Reload" enabled.

If you want to remove the `live-preview-root` element entirely, you have to disabled "Browser Link" and "Hot Reload", as suggested in the related StackOverflow question.

---

I like having "Hot Reload", so instead I added a CSS script in the development environment to `display: none` the `live-preview-root` element; this fixed my grid layout styling.

In your layout file:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <!-- Hide the browser-link element, which screws up our styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/browser-link.css"/>
</environment>
```

`browser-link.css`:

```css
live-preview-root {
    display: none;
}
```